# Selenium get textarea error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrap in a website using Selenium and Python, I got stucked in a field called 'textarea' by the website. This is how the website HTML calls the area where I'm trying to extract text:

```
<textarea class="script" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" readonly="readonly" id="script">
```

After this code comes the text that I want to get. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
getCode = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('textarea')
```

My problem is that It does not recognize the text by the following codes:

```
getCode.submit()
getCode.click()  
getCode.text()
```

This is the code error that I always get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "ScprL.py", line 55, in module
>       print (repr(getCode.text))
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

I would apreciate your help!

Comment: You should extract the webElement from the list first like this `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('textarea')[0]` if the first text area you want is the one you want

Comment: do you want only above HTML code data for you want all textarea field data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `driver.find_element_by_tag_name` instead

When you use `driver.find_elements` you get a list of webElements. You should extract the element from the list

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('textarea')[0]
print element.text
```

If you have multiple textareas on the page, then you should try to finding the one you need like below

```
textareas = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('textarea')
for i, textarea in enumerate(textareas):
    print '{} is at index {}'.format(textarea.text, i)
```

And then use the appropriate `i` value to get `textareas[i]`

Comment: That's It! Removed the 's' from 'elements' and it stopped getting a list so I could get the simple text that I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: if you need a single text then you do not need to use list ... list is being used on that place where you need to iterate multiple return element..

Answer (score 1):

As you are using driver.**find_elements**_by_tag_name('textarea') it will retrieve list of web elements. Need to collect these web elements then iterate one by one then get text of each of web element.  below is the example in java,

```
List<WebElement> ButtonNamelist =   driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".locatorHere"));

 System.out.println(ButtonNamelist.size());

  for(int i=0;i<ButtonNamelist.size();i++){

 System.out.println(ButtonNamelist.get(i).getText());

}
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions for each locator in selenium: "find_element**s**" and "find_element". The difference is pretty simple: the first one return a list of elements that satisfy selector and the second one returns first found element. You can read more about locating elements [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html).

So you either need to change your function to `find_element_by_tag_name` or to retrieve first element from list: `find_element_by_tag_name()[0]`.